# snowflake time travel to get historical data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we have SCD type 1 table and the request is to get historical data for each month. How do I accomplish this using snowflake time travel? for example, if I run the query in the month of august, it should give me data for the month of July, 1 to July, 31. If not time travel, please suggest another approach to it. Thanks

Comment: do you have enterprise account or above? if not the time travel is only available for 7 days. Also you have to pay for the all data volume changes over this time, which for tables with large churn might be higher than you want/expect.

Comment: possible a better option might be to use Streams and build a daily/weekly change (SC2) table, so you can better maintain the grain of detail that you need, while balancing data/compute costs to achieve this. Aka, you have to know what you are trying to do, and how much you are prepared to pay to do it, and how quickly to need to bring this online, and how you might plan to transition a more optimal solution, for your given needs.

Comment: We have enterprise level and time retention is set to 90 days. Please let me know how time travel can be used in this case. I am thinking to write a view and do the time travel to capture the historical snapshot of this table. However, how do I pass in the date range for this time travel using at timestamp(=>..)?

Comment: Havwe you tried creating a stored procedure with a date parameter? I can't find any doco that indicates whether time travel is supported or not. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview Regardless, this pattern has been built many times before the advent of time travel.

Comment: Using Time Travel in this way doesn't seem like a great idea. It will give you a point-in-time query i.e. what did my data look like on the 1st August - but I don't know what you mean, in this context, by the "data for the month of July, 1 to July, 31" - as the data can change throughout that time period. If your data has a loaded/updated date you could just use that; if you genuinely need the history then I would convert your table to SCD2. As time travel is limited to 90 days you are limited in the data you can see using this method - and a solution with such a restriction seems unwise

Comment: However, if you do want to use time travel then can you clarify what your issue is? Assuming you have read the documentation on how to use time travel in queries, please update your question with the SQL you've managed to write and explain precisely the issue you are facing.

Comment: As others have commented, time travel is not positioned for fulfilling the need of slowly changing dimensions. The most constraining factor is the 90 day limit. Most SCD applications will require more than 90 days history. Either streams or dynamic tables would be a better option. See https://medium.com/snowflake/slowly-changing-dimensions-with-dynamic-tables-d0d76582ff31 for a bare bones approach to SCD1 and SCD2 using dynamic tables.